# says i don't have wiringpi module when runing code at startup

Tags: boot, wiringpi, systemd-startup

I have a code set up to run at boot, and it works fine when I start it via terminal, but it doesn't run at boot. I opened the terminal, and this is what I saw:

```
Running at boot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/program.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wiringpi
ImportError: No module named wiringpi
```

I know I have it on the pi as it works when I start it manually, but for some reason it doesn't work at boot. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you run at boot? How do you run it? What terminal do you open to see the message?

Comment: @Ingo, i run a python program from bash.rc at boot and when i open the terminal. i open the terminal the pi comes with by default.

Comment: What bash.rc do you mean? In `/etc/` is no bash.rc. There is a `/home/pi/.bashrc` (with leading dot). Do you mean that? What operating system do you use? What version of it?

Comment: @Ingo yes. I use raspbian. i updated and upgraded everything just yesterday.

Comment: What bash.rc do you mean?

Comment: @Ingo, the /home/pi/.bashrc

Comment: Does your program only run once a short time, maybe to initialize something, or does it run always in the background as service?

Comment: @Ingo, the full python script can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045458/this-variable-wont-change?noredirect=1#comment111663014_63045458

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see at a glance what this program do. Does it run once a short time or does it always run in the background?

Comment: @Ingo, always in the background until i manually stop it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `~/.bashrc` to run a program at boot up. It is to configure `bash` and runs only with bash sessions and not at boot up of the RasPi. To have a service started on boot up you best use a systemd Unit file. Try it by creating a Unit file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit myprogram.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=My python3 script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/program.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Manage it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable --now myprogram.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl status myprogram.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop myprogram.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start myprogram.service
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `systemd` for starting a program at boot is `cron`. If you've not used `cron` to schedule jobs, you may find it easier than `systemd`. Here's how:

1. Open the "scheduler" for `cron` - the `crontab`:

```
$ crontab -e
```

This will open your `crontab` in the editor you have chosen (`nano` is a good choice)

2. Add the job to the `crontab` - add the following line in the editor:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 15; /home/pi/program.py >> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1 )
```

3. Save the file, exit the editor, and reboot to test. If there are errors they will be written to the file `/home/pi/cronjoblog`

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is the module is present, but not where it's being looked for.  2 things, running at boot it may be running as root.  This changes paths among other things,  also, there's *when* it's started relative to other things being set up.  So, first, try using the full path name ( import /... ??/wiringpi  ) ( wherever it is ).  If that doesn't work, delay the start.   The "correct" way to start jobs on boot ( I don't know it well ) does have a way to say either "requires" or "wait for".